# Do Google Analytics filters accept regex for IP address rules?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I usually use regular expressions a lot in GA filters, but I'm also usually adding "custom" filters.

The IP address predefined filter accepts values per the screenshot below
[image: IP address predefined filter]

Usually I'd expect this to have an option that says "matches pattern", but I'm wondering if "contains" might do it.

The official docs from Google suggest making multiple rules for multiple IPs, but when you have staff spread across many different offices this becomes very time consuming.

The official docs do say that the `*` character works as a wildcard with IPv4 addresses. I'm wondering if that's the case due to being regex enabled (i.e., `.*`) or if it's just a regular wildcard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions for IP filtering, but you need to create a custom type rule, instead of predefined. Key settings for this:
[image]

You can even find tools to create the RegEx based on the provided IP range, e.g. [this one](https://www.analyticsmarket.com/freetools/ipregex/). (No affiliation, just recommendation.)